# Is there a general term to refer to a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, notation, terminology

By "general" I mean a formula that describes all polynomials using letters to represent coefficients and powers. For example, the "general" term for a quadratic is $ax^{2}+bx+c$, the "general" term for a 2-dimensional vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ is $\left[\begin{array}{}
{v_1} \\ 
{v_2} \\
\end{array}\right]$,
just so you understand what I mean by "general".

Now, my question is: Is there a general way to refer to polynomials? I've seen before $a_{1}x^{n}+a_2x^{n-1}+a_3x^{n-2}\cdots +a_nx^{0}$ ,but it seems overly redundant, it's a little hard to look at, and the "..." can be confusing and misleading at times. Is there a better way to represent this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way... you may have noticed that I wrote [v_1 \\ v_2] for the vector instead of the 2*1 matrix... this is because I don't actually know how to do it that way. I tried the built-in LaTeX matrix command, but it didn't work. If anybody here knows how to make it look like an actual 2*1 matrix, editing the question would be greatly appreciated! :]

Comment: Update: Thank you so much to whoever edited it!

Comment: If you don't like the ellipsis ($\ldots$) you can use the sigma notation: $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$. It's the usual way of writing polynomials that avoids the use of ellipsis.

Comment: In the literature you can also se the polynomials denoted simply as $p(x)$, $p_n(x)$, $p[x]$ or $p$. It depends on the context